# Python pandas merge can't find column name

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I've got two pandas DataFrames:

main:

```
          id        date   store_nbr   item_nbr   unit_sales   onpromotion
0          0  2013-01-01          25     103665         7.00           NaN
1          1  2013-01-01          25     105574         1.00           NaN
2          2  2013-01-01          25     105575         2.00           NaN
3          3  2013-01-01          25     108079         1.00           NaN
4          4  2013-01-01          25     108701         1.00           NaN
5          5  2013-01-01          25     108786         3.00           NaN
6          6  2013-01-01          25     108797         1.00           NaN
7          7  2013-01-01          25     108952         1.00           NaN
8          8  2013-01-01          25     111397        13.00           NaN
9          9  2013-01-01          25     114790         3.00           NaN
10        10  2013-01-01          25     114800         1.00           NaN
11        11  2013-01-01          25     115267         1.00           NaN
12        12  2013-01-01          25     115611         1.00           NaN
```

and items:

```
      item_nbr            family  class  perishable
0        96995         GROCERY I   1093           0
1        99197         GROCERY I   1067           0
2       103501          CLEANING   3008           0
3       103520         GROCERY I   1028           0
4       103665      BREAD/BAKERY   2712           1
5       105574         GROCERY I   1045           0
6       105575         GROCERY I   1045           0
```

of course both are much longer than those few records.

I wanted do join them using common item_nbr column, but no matter how I try to join them, I've got a KeyError:

```
joined = pd.merge(main, items, on='item_nbr')
KeyError: 'item_nbr'
```

Am I missing something?
I've read this site and found no solution there:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: There might be spaces in column names so do `main.columns = main.columns.str.strip()` and `items.columns=items.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: Un-freaking-beliveable. Data is loaded from two CSVs, one with spaces between columns and one without. Your solution or simply removing spaces from CSV solves the problem. Please post it as an answer, so I can choose it as solution.

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be spaces in column names so do

```
main.columns = main.columns.str.strip() 
#and 
items.columns=items.columns.str.strip()
```

You are now good to merge the dataframes

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to remove whitespace on import. Something like:

```
pd.read_csv(file,sep='\s*,\s*') # delimiter includes x*whitespace before and after
```

Example code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# Sample data with whitespace after column
data = '''\
A ,B
1,2'''

(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data)).columns.tolist() ==
 pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),sep='\s*,\s*').columns.tolist())
```

Returns

```
False
```